# Using c ++ class in jni

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I apologize for my bad English.

In an android application I want to use the code in the [link](https://gist.github.com/berak/1c97115b3b343f1e9440bb22cf77fc76).

How do I use c ++ class in jni? How do I resolve this error? Thank you.

OpenCV version : 3.4.5

[my cpp folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZScTu.png)

Error line in native-lib.cpp : CV_DNN_REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS(Crop, CropLayer);

native-lib.cpp :

```
#include "CropLayer.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include "opencv2/dnn/layer.details.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"


using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;
using namespace std;


extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sercan_outliers_scanner_NativeClass_nana(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                                         jlong net_addr,
                                                                         jlong input_mat_addr,
                                                                         jlong result_mat_addr) {

    //**************** ERROR LINE ********************************
    CV_DNN_REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS(Crop, CropLayer);
    //**************** ERROR LINE ********************************

    Mat* pic = (Mat *)input_mat_addr;
    Mat* cannedImage = (Mat *)result_mat_addr;
    Net* net = (Net *)net_addr;
    Size reso((int)(pic->size().width * 0.18), (int)(pic->size().height * 0.18));
    //Size reso(500, 500);
    Mat blob = blobFromImage(
            (*pic),
            1.0,
            reso,
            Scalar(104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),
            false,
            false
            );


    net->setInput(blob);
    cv::Mat out = net->forward();
    cv::resize(out.reshape(1, reso.height), out, pic->size());
    out.convertTo(*cannedImage, CV_8U, 255.0, 0.0);

    out.release();

}
```

CropLayer.h :

```
#ifndef OUTLIERS_CROPLAYER_H
#define OUTLIERS_CROPLAYER_H

#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>

class CropLayer : public cv::dnn::Layer
{
public:
    CropLayer(const cv::dnn::LayerParams &params): Layer(params){}

    static cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::Layer> create(cv::dnn::LayerParams& params){
        return cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::Layer>(new CropLayer(params));
    }

    virtual bool getMemoryShapes(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &inputs,
                                 const int requiredOutputs,
                                 std::vector<std::vector<int> > &outputs,
                                 std::vector<std::vector<int> > &internals) const CV_OVERRIDE
    {
        CV_UNUSED(requiredOutputs); CV_UNUSED(internals);
        std::vector<int> outShape(4);
        outShape[0] = inputs[0][0];  // batch size
        outShape[1] = inputs[0][1];  // number of channels
        outShape[2] = inputs[1][2];
        outShape[3] = inputs[1][3];
        outputs.assign(1, outShape);
        return false;
    }

    virtual void forward(cv::InputArrayOfArrays inputs_arr,
                         cv::OutputArrayOfArrays outputs_arr,
                         cv::OutputArrayOfArrays internals_arr) CV_OVERRIDE
    {

        std::vector<cv::Mat> inputs, outputs;
        inputs_arr.getMatVector(inputs);
        outputs_arr.getMatVector(outputs);

        cv::Mat& inp = inputs[0];
        cv::Mat& out = outputs[0];

        int ystart = (inp.size[2] - out.size[2]) / 2;
        int xstart = (inp.size[3] - out.size[3]) / 2;
        int yend = ystart + out.size[2];
        int xend = xstart + out.size[3];

        const int batchSize = inp.size[0];
        const int numChannels = inp.size[1];
        const int height = out.size[2];
        const int width = out.size[3];

        int sz[] = { (int)batchSize, numChannels, height, width };
        out.create(4, sz, CV_32F);
        for(int i=0; i<batchSize; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<numChannels; j++)
            {
                cv::Mat plane(inp.size[2], inp.size[3], CV_32F, inp.ptr<float>(i,j));
                cv::Mat crop = plane(cv::Range(ystart,yend), cv::Range(xstart,xend));
                cv::Mat targ(height, width, CV_32F, out.ptr<float>(i,j));
                crop.copyTo(targ);
            }
        }
    }
};

#endif //OUTLIERS_CROPLAYER_H
```

Error :

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/cevat/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/cevat/AndroidStudioProjects/outliers2/outliersscanner/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so
FAILED: : && /home/cevat/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi23 --gcc-toolchain=/home/cevat/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/cevat/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -std=gnu++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  /home/cevat/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/23/liblog.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so -latomic -lm && :
/home/cevat/AndroidStudioProjects/outliers2/outliersscanner/src/main/cpp/CropLayer.h:40: error: undefined reference to 'cv::_InputArray::getMatVector(std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&) const'
/home/cevat/AndroidStudioProjects/outliers2/outliersscanner/src/main/cpp/CropLayer.h:41: error: undefined reference to 'cv::_InputArray::getMatVector(std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&) const'
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o:native-lib.cpp:vtable for CropLayer: error: undefined reference to 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::Layer::finalize(std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat*, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat*> > const&, std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&)'
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o:native-lib.cpp:vtable for CropLayer: error: undefined reference to 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::Layer::forward(std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat*, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat*> >&, std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&, std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&)'
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o:native-lib.cpp:vtable for CropLayer: error: undefined reference to 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::Layer::initHalide(std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::BackendWrapper>, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::BackendWrapper> > > const&)'
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o:native-lib.cpp:vtable for CropLayer: error: undefined reference to 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::Layer::initInfEngine(std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::BackendWrapper>, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::BackendWrapper> > > const&)'
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o:native-lib.cpp:vtable for CropLayer: error: undefined reference to 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::Layer::applyHalideScheduler(cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::BackendNode>&, std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat*, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat*> > const&, std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Mat> > const&, int) const'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required()

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniIncludes)

add_library(native-lib
    SHARED

    src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
        src/main/cpp/CropLayer.h)

add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

find_library(log-lib
             log)

target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib} lib_opencv)
```

Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0"
    kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.5.0'

    implementation project(':openCVLibrary345')


}
```

Comment: Here's a tutorial I made to set up native C++ OpenCV with Android, hope it helps!